# Can't get basic example from react-navigation to work correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get a basic `AppContainer` to work in react-navigation but am having some trouble.

[This example here](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/hello-world-v3) works perfectly fine on snack.expo.io and even works fine when I run it on my device off of snack. However, when I copy paste the exact code into VSCode and push it to my device, it errors out with:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `NavigationContainer`.
```

The code is the exact same, yet errors out on my Android device. Am I missing a dependency or something?

Thanks!

EDIT:

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-25.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your `package.json` file to the question? The dependencies will be different from the expo snack

Comment: Do you have ```AppRegistry``` in your root app ?

Comment: joshkmartinez Added. Which dependencies am I missing?

Comment: Nazır Dogan No.

Comment: Is that the entire `package.json` file? If so, which command do you use to start the app?

Comment: Siavas `expo start`